# How do I force a Visual Basic 2008 function to only be accessed via events?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, events, event-handling

I want some event handling functions to only be able to be accessed via raised events and not called from the program.

Such as:

```
Public Event Event1(Byval TheText as string)
private sub Event1Handler(Byval TheText as string) handles me.Event1
   msgbox("Hi")
end sub
```

I want this code to execute the function:`RaiseEvent Event1("Hi")`

But I do not want this code to execute the function:`Event1Handler("Hi")`

Is there a declaration or some other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the function and click "find all references". Do this periodically to make sure nothing references it directly

Answer (score 2):

There's no other way than embed this logic into a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx).